# ajax POST function does not get triggered in Node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, pug

So, I have this issue with the POST request. I need it in order to update info without reloading the page. Here is my pug code:

```
.tinder--buttons
            form(id="form1")
                button#love(type="submit")
                    i.fa.fa-heart
```

And here is the code from the javascript file:

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function () {
        console.log("Got there");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "gono",
            data: {
                place: places[0].placeId, 
            },
            success: function (result) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I already tried changing the description to

```
$("button").on('click', function()
$("#love").on('click', function()
```

and other variation but it doesn't even do the request to begin with, as the console log does not work. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: You mean the click is not triggering ? or it's not making service call?

Comment: Neither really, even the click does not get triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach event to parent container by using `.on('click')` which will be there in DOM always and pass the target element's selector as second parameter like below.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', "#love", function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "gono",
                data: {
                    place: places[0].placeId, 
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```